# Cloudflare changes my Tor Exit Node

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, configuration, exit-relays, identity-change, cloudflare

I set up in Tor Browser Exitnodes {lu} StrictNodes 1 and it works very well on all websites. But when I go to one website where they have cloudflare, I will see the "Checking If The Site Connection is Secure" screen. That's okay, but when I give New Tor Circuit for this site, IP address Luxembourg will jump for a few seconds, but then it will immediately disappear and join another country. Why do it?

Comment: `StrictNodes` doesn't apply to `ExitNodes`, so it's not doing anything in this case.